# Form with Upload file attachment

Tags: php, forms

I am using contact.php for contact form. I added an attachment field for upload file/image, pdf, docx in contact form using . But i can not integrate php functions for file attachment. I am weak in php, but this is very important for me to add this in my contact form.

Please someone help me. My form code and php code are given below. Thanks in advance.

//** This is html markup

```
<form id="Frmgroupa" class="form-style" method="post" onsubmit="return validator4(this)" action="contact.php">
                  
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_name">Name of Candidate *</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['name'] : '' ?>" placeholder="" required autofocus />
                                    
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="form_need">State</label>
                                    <select id="State" class="form-control" name="State" placeholder="" required autofocus>
                                    <option value="UTTAR PRADESH">UTTAR PRADESH</option>
                                    </select>                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p>Address Proof *</p>
                                <div class="custom-file mb-3">
                                    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="Address_Proof" name="filename" >
                                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
                        
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p>Identity Proof *</p>
                                <div class="custom-file mb-3">
                                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="Identity_Proof" name="filename">
                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
                        
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-3d" value="SUBMIT" id="submit-button" />
                  <?php unset($_SESSION['cf_returndata']); ?>
                </form>
```

//* This is the contact.php code

```
<?php
$myemail = "amit.joshi98@gmail.com";

$subject = "file Upload";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */

$name = check_input($_POST['name'], "Enter your name");
$State = $_POST['State'];

/* If URL is not valid set $website to empty */
if (!preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/+[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/i", $website))
{
    $website = 'http://google.com';
}

/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "Hello!

Your contact form has been submitted by:

Name: $name
State: $State

End of message
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: thank-you.html');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem = '')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}
function show_error($myError)
{
?>
    <html>
    <body>

    <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
    <?php echo $myError; ?>

    </body>
    </html>
<?php
    exit();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to write the following phrase in the form tag

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Like this ...

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and then in `process.php` file check submit and save file in your path

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}
```

for limit file Type

```
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

for last check error and set message for user

```
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
```

you can Check if file already exists or Check file size
But i suggest you write an uploader function for the file and use it wherever you want.

In this example, photo file types were used that you can change according to your needs